# In CodeBlocks 16.01, how would I get the command line arguments window to pop up on my screen?

Tags: c, codeblocks

I'm trying to set command line arguments for a project I'm working on in C Programming, but every time I click Set Program's Arguments under the Project tab, the window does not appear for me to set the program's arguments. How would I fix this?

Comment: Is your c code in a project or just a free file

Comment: It's in a project folder

Comment: If the window doesn't appear it may be a problem with codeblocks. As a work around, you could just run it from the command line

Comment: But to do that would I drag the free file from the project folder to the command line in order to set arguments?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.. what OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Windows

Comment: Then you should look up how to compile c code from the command line in Windows. There are tons of resources written on it